# Creating Trunks in FreePBX

Tags: virtualbox, asterisk, voip, pbx, freepbx

I have already set up my FreePBX (PIAF-Ast11-FS-Skype) in Oracle VM VirtualBox.
I've also installed X-Lite 4.0 (a voip phone system).

Now, I am about to create trunk for it but where do I get this information. Please attached link.
https://monosnap.com/image/qnV2oREpK1mbFcpWNjb4l0iygHSW9y

Answer (score 0):

You have get contract with any provider

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/VOIP+Service+Providers

After that you can request needed info at provider's support /check provider's help center.